# Oracle query taking a long time

Tags: sql, oracle, runtime

A condensed version of my query is below (because of how many variables there are), when I run the sub-query by itself it runs in 2 seconds, yet when I surround it, it takes upwards of half an hour.  I have checked all column names - twice.  Why is this happening? And what can I do to fix it?

`SELECT
    Amount, Comments, FirstName, LastName, TermName, AdjustmentType, Void_Indicator
FROM
(
    Select
        c.amount amount,
        c.comments comments,
        p.firstname firstname,
        p.lastname lastname,
        e.termname termname,
        c.adjustmenttype adjustmenttype,
        b.voidindicator void_indicator
    From
        ChargesDTL c,
        ChargesHDR b,
        PeopleHDL p,
        TermMaster e
    Where
    (
        b.studentnumber=p.studentnumber and
        c.termid = e.term_id and
        b.adjustmentnumber=c.adjustmentnumber and
        p.personID=b.personID and
        b.locationcode='12'
    )
    Union
    Select
        c.amount amount,
        c.comments comments,
        p1.firstname firstname,
        p1.lastname lastname,
        e.termname termname,
        c.adjustmenttype adjustmenttype,
        b.voidindicator void_indicator
    From
        ChargesDTL c,
        ChargesHDR b,
        PeopleHDL p1,
        TermMaster e
    Where
    (
        b.studentnumber=p.studentnumber and
        c.termid = e.term_id and
        b.adjustmentnumber=c.adjustmentnumber and
        p1.personId = b.personId and
        b.locationcode='13'
    )
    order by
        adjustmenttype
)`

Comment: This could be one query.  The Derived Table is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question.  Your query can be easily condensed down to one single query with a set of join statements.  The Union and Derived table is completely unnecessary.

```
SELECT
    c.amount,
    c.comments,
    p.firstname,
    p.lastname,
    e.termname,
    c.adjustmenttype,
    b.voidindicator
FROM ChargesDTL c
INNER JOIN TermMaster e ON e.termid = c.term_id 
INNER JOIN ChargesHDR b ON b.adjustmentnumber = c.adjustmentnumber
INNER JOIN PeopleHDL p ON p.personID = b.personID AND p.studentnumber = b.studentnumber
WHERE
    (b.locationcode = '12' OR b.locationcode = '13')
ORDER BY c.adjustmenttype
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Select  c.amount amount,
    c.comments comments,
    p1.firstname firstname,
    p1.lastname lastname,
    e.termname termname,
    c.adjustmenttype adjustmenttype,
    b.voidindicator void_indicator
From ChargesDTL c,
     ChargesHDR b
     on b.adjustmentnumber = c.adjustmentnumber join
    PeopleHDL p
    on b.studentnumber = p.studentnumber and
       p.personId = b.personId join
    TermMaster e
    on c.termid = e.term_id
Whereb.locationcode in ('12', '13')
order by adjustmenttype;
```

You should learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax.  The comma syntax has been obsolete (but fully supported) for decades.